# array de 100 posicoes para matriz de 10x10

Tags: javascript

Tenho um array unidimensional de 100 posicoes e como fazer com que eu desenhe uma matriz (table) de 10x10 usando um loop for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x= [];

for (i=0; i< 100; i++)
{
x[i] = "X";
}


var texto;

texto = "<table>";

for (i=0; i< (x.length/100); i++)
{

texto += "<tr>";

for (i=(x.length)-1; i< x.length; i++) //como resolver isso? ????
{
texto += "<td>" + x[i] + "</td>";
} 

texto += "</tr>";


}
texto += "</table>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = texto;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x= [];

for (i=0; i< 100; i++)
{
x[i] = "X";
}

x[23] = "Y";
x[88] = "Z";


var texto;

texto = "<table>";

for (i=0; i < (x.length/10); i++)
{
texto += "<tr>";
for (y = (((x.length/100) * (i*10))) ; y < (((x.length/100) * (i+1)) * 10); y++)
{
texto += "<td>" + x[y] + "</td>";
} 
texto += "</tr>";

}
texto += "</table>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = texto;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O que eu fiz não precisou usar o auto incremento dento do loop, conforme mostra o código do @Diego Felipe. Mas mesmo assim obrigado.

Comment: Muito bom sua alternativa de código. Marque sua resposta como resolvida para que outros possam consultar futuramente,

Comment: Como faço para marcar como resolvida?

Comment: Só clicar na seta verde abaixo do contador da resposta.

Comment: obrigado. cliquei  na seta mas foi exibido um aviso que so posso resolver depois de dois dias.

Comment: Quando você responde sua própria pergunta, o sistema exige que para aceitá-la, a mesma deve estar publicada há pelo menos dois dias. Não sei ao certo qual é a finalidade dessa restrição.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente você vai precisar de 2 laços, um pra controlar a direção vertical(linhas da tabela) e outro interno pra controlar as linhas horizontais(colunas):

```js
var x = [];

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  x[i] = "X" + i;
};


texto = "<table>";

for (i = 0; i < (x.length);) {

  texto += "<tr>";

  for (c = 0; c < 10; c++) //como resolver isso? ????
  {
    texto += "<td>" + x[i] + "</td>";
    i++
  }

  texto += "</tr>";


}
texto += "</table>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = texto;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```